# Get ACI container image without using ACR username and password in Azure Logic App? i.e. using Managed Identity

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-container-instances

I am using Logic app to create ACI Container group. I want to use managed identity to pull the container image from ACR, instead of using UserName and password to connect to the ACR as shown below. How to accomplish the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Azure Key Vault to store those information. You can turn on the Managed Identity for the Logic App which can have access to Key Vault secrets/keys.

Following blog provides detailed instructions on how to access Key Vault from Logic Apps with Managed Identity:

https://devkimchi.com/2018/10/24/accessing-key-vault-from-logic-apps-with-managed-identity/

Comment: That we are already doing, but our security team is asking us to move that to managed identity. Basically, they want us to disable Admin access key feature on Azure container instances i.e. real images only using RBAC roles.